# Getting Wrong answer on codechef

Tags: python

Pooja would like to withdraw X $US from an ATM. The cash machine will only accept the transaction if X is a multiple of 5, and Pooja's account balance has enough cash to perform the withdrawal transaction (including bank charges). For each successful withdrawal the bank charges 0.50 $US. Calculate Pooja's account balance after an attempted transaction.

**Input**

Positive integer 0 < X <= 2000 - the amount of cash which Pooja wishes to withdraw.

Nonnegative number 0<= Y <= 2000 with two digits of precision - Pooja's initial account balance.

**Output**

Output the account balance after the attempted transaction, given as a number with two digits of precision. If there is not enough money in the account to complete the transaction, output the current bank balance.

**Example - Successful Transaction**

*Input:*
30 120.00

*Output:*
89.50

**Example - Incorrect Withdrawal Amount (not multiple of 5)**

*Input:*
42 120.00

*Output:*
120.00

**Example - Insufficient Funds**

*Input:*
300 120.00

*Output:*
120.00

I ran the code based on the test cases given, I got them right , but when i submitted the solution it says "wrong answer". Please help.

```
y=0
x=0
balance=0
x,y=map(float, input().split())
x=int(x)
if(0<=y<=2000 and 0<x<=2000 and y>x):
    if(x%5==0):
        balance=y-x-(0.50)
    else:
        balance=y
else:
    balance=y
print(balance)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not handling this case:

*Input:* 10 10.01

*Output:* -0.4900000000000002

`y>x` is not sufficient for testing for account underflow.

Also, if you are submitting your code as Python2, `input()` behaves differently in Python2 than Python3.